# Network Connectivity of Windows Failover Servers

Tags: failover, failovercluster

I have two servers running Windows Server 2016 with the Failover Cluster role, each of which is running as a Hyper-V virtual machine on a different host.

The servers are on the same subnet and are able to successfully ping eachother.

However, when I run the cluster validation, I receive the following errors:

> Network interfaces  - Ethernet and  - Ethernet are on the same cluster network, yet address  is not reachable from  using UDP on port 3343.

and this one:

> Node  is not reachable from node . It is necessary that each cluster node can communicate each other cluster node by a minimum of one network path (though multiple paths are recommended to avoid a single point of failure). Please verify that existing networks are configured properly or add additional networks.

How is this possible?

Comment: When you install Failover Cluster it *should* open all relevant ports in the Firewall. Can you check this is done for port 3343/UDP ? or, maybe you are running a thirdparty firewall ?